# Getting data from php file using JQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an empty table and the table contains 3 different headings.

I need to get the individual data from a PHP script using jquery.get method and insert each row into the table.

Quite unsure on how to do this. It's just returning the whole data set when I click on the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.get("file.php",
      {name: "name",
       address: "address",
      type: "type"
},
      function(data){
        $("#name").append(data);
      });
    });
  });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3> Table for Stadiums </h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='name'></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  </table>

  <button> Click </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely, the data is coming back as an Object and not just as Text. So just appending the data is not going to work as expected. You should use the Console or Network tabs in Web Tools to examine the results. What is being sent back? What is an example of the data you are expecting?

Comment: Each row should display a name, address, type, etc. for Stadiums

Comment: Would still need an example of the data being returned to the GET call. Sounds like it would be more complex JSON data. Please update your post with an example of the data being returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate `data` to form a table, please take a reference from below code for the same, as you can use the same `renderTable` method, just pass your data object to it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  this.data = {
    "Students": [{
        "id": "1",
        "hometown": "London",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "8",
        "name": "Lee",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "hometown": "NY",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "9",
        "name": "Shaldon",
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "hometown": "Paris",
        "gender": "Female",
        "GPA": "7",
        "name": "Julie",
      }
    ]
  };
  
  this.renderTable = function(Students) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>ID</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].id + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>HomeTown</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].hometown + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>Gender</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].gender + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>GPA</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].GPA + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>NAME</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].name + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<hr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
    }
  }

  this.renderTable(this.data.Students);

  console.log(this.data.Students);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The point of this is to use the .get() function that jquery provides

Answer (score 0):

[Twisty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463319/twisty) said right: we don't know what data comes back from the server! 
Assuming that file.php returns an array of stadiums your callback function should look something like this:

```
function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < stadiums.length; i++) {
        var tr = "<tr>";
        tr += "<td class='name'>" + stadiums[i].name + "</td>";
        tr += "<td class='address'>" + stadiums[i].address + "</td>";
        tr += "<td class='type'>" + stadiums[i].type + "</td>";
        tr += "</tr>";
        $("table").append(tr);    
    }
});
```